# Xamarin IOS WebClient execute in Thread

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin, webclient

Is an good Idea to run WebClient request like `UploadAsync` or `DownloadAsync` into a thread from a `UIViewController`.

Sometimes my request never came back, and `OnUploadDataCompleted` / `OnDownloadDataCompleted` never called. I got an overlay that tells to user to be patient, but I want to let the possibility to user to cancel when it become very long.

1 / I wondering if launching the request into a thread, and when user press cancel button, I terminate the process is a good Idea or Really bad thing todo.

2/ User need to be informed about process, so thread will update with `InvokeOnMainThread`, is a good way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is a good idea.  You can call CancelAsync() on your WebClient object.  Also, the DataCompleted callback should always get called unless an exception is thrown.  The other possibility is to reduce the timeout so you can respond to the user in a more timely manner.  As I remember the default timeout was something like 60 seconds.

Comment: After reading your anwser, you're approach seems to be the right things to do.